# How to add new Contact record from separate browser using HTML in CRM 2013

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to add new contact record from HTML browser using javacript with suporting jquery files like JSON2.js, jquery1.4.1.min.js along with odata call.

But unable to create records.

ODATA call works fine in CRM Form, but fails if calling from HTML Page.

This there any other thing need to add.

Comment: Write the code that fails please, maybe it's because you need to call "window" before calling the method you want.

Comment: Thanks Sxntk. Also im not calling from CRM context. This HTML page is in separate from CRM. For example this HTML page is available in "New Folder" in Desktop with Supporting javasScript files.

Comment: I am not familiar with external request with oData, all of them I made it with fetch and executes. You should try to make this with fetch or and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the security sandbox in the browser itself to protect against cross site scripting attacks. It prevents your JavaScripts that came from one domain (file://desktop/new folder) where your HTML file is located to post to a different domain (http://crmserver/) where your CRM server resides.

Why not load the HTML page into the CRM web resources under Customization?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx